# Update half of results of SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL I need to update half of the records of a query's results to set a column to a certain attribute.

So something like...

```
UPDATE some_table SET some_column='some_value'
WHERE some_query = 'something' LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*)/2 FROM some_table);
```

But this will give me a syntax error.  I am wondering if this is possible and how to perform this in MySQL.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What are you 'ordering' by?

Comment: I don't need to order, I just need to affect half of the matching rows.

Answer (score 1):

E.g.:

```
UPDATE my_table a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.*, @i:=@i+1 rank FROM my_table x, (SELECT @i:=0) vars ORDER BY id) b 
    ON b.id = a.id 
   SET a.val = 'a' 
 WHERE rank % 2 = 1;
```

This updates every other row (which is approximately equal to 'half the rows')

Comment: If it is every other row, it would be half if the count is even but not if the count is odd, correct?

Comment: There is no need for a subquery if the ORDER doesn't matter: http://rextester.com/LXD60449

Answer (score 0):

You could add a row_number and only affect rows whose row number is <= half of the total number of rows... something like;

```
WITH Numbered as (
SELECT *,
    row_number() as RowNum
FROM some_table 
)
UPDATE Numbered
SET some_row = 'some_value'
WHERE RowNum <= (SELECT Count(*) / 2 FROM Numbered)
```

Comment: Bear in mind if there are an odd number of rows you cannot by definition update exactly half, so consider what you would like to happen to the one left over row in this case.

Comment: "In MySQL..." ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if mysql have function ROW_NUMBER, but in T-SQL you can use somethin like this:

```
with a (rownum, some_column) 
as 
(select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by some_column) as rownum, some_column 
    from some_table 
    where some_query = 'something')
update a 
    set some_column='some_value'
from a
where rownum <= (select count(1)/2 from a)
```